# Jenkins CI deploying docker image on Heroku

Tags: docker, jenkins, heroku, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins CI and use it to build (mvn) and containerize (docker) my app using Jenkins scripted pipeline. Lastly, I want to deploy my container to Heroku dyno (I have already created an app).

I have followed this documentation https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime and have been successfully pushed my docker image to registry.heroku.com/sunset-sailing-4049/web.

The issue is since this announcement https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/1426 I now need to explicitly execute "heroku container:release web" in order to get my docker container running from registry to app dyno. This is where I am royally stuck. See my below issues:

1. Heroku is not recognized by Jenkins. (My Jenkins is running on ec2, I have installed heroku toolbelt as ec2-user user. But Jenkins throws error: heroku: command not found). How do I resolve this issue?
2. How to do "heroku login" from Jenkins, since the login command prompts for browser login. I have added ssh key but I do not know how to use it from the command line, hence Jenkins "shell script"

The only other way I could think of is deploying via heroku pipeline using a dummy git repo onto which Jenkins will upload the source code on a successful build.

Would really appreciate your help solving the above 2 issues.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need install heroku as user under which jenkins is running. Or if you installed it globally it may be not in PATH of user under which jenkins is running.
   There are multiple options for setting PATH:

   - Set for specific command.
     If your job is pipeline just wrap heroku command in [withEnv](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#withenv-set-environment-variables) closure:

     `withEnv(['PATH+HEROKU=/use/local/bin/']) {
     your heroku command here
     }`
   - Set path for jenkins slave: go to [Manage Jenkins] -> [Manage Nodes], configure your node and set  Environment variable `PATH` to `$PATH:/use/local/bin/`. This way all jobs running on slave will get environment variable injected.
2. For automated cli interactions heroku supports API tokens. You can either put it in `~/.netrc` on build machine or supply as environment variable (see [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/authentication#api-token-storage)).

Comment: When I do which Heroku it is /use/local/bin/Heroku. Can you please provide some instructions on how do I add it to user under which Jenkins is running

Comment: @AliNahid added to answer

Answer (score 0):

(writing here incase someone is facing the same scenario)
ok I took @vladimir's suggestion and did the below:

**Heroku command (for jenkins running on ec2):**

- The below command is needed to push a built docker image to heroku via jenkins/or other ci/cd tool; Because of a recent change (https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/1426) pushing to heroku registry isn't sufficient any longer. In order to execute the below command you need to install heroku toolbelt.

  heroku container:release web
- Install snap on amazon linux like below:

follow instruction to enable epel https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/add-repositories.html

Then Modify /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo. Under the section marked [epel] , change enabled=0 to enabled=1.

Then do

```
sudo yum install epel-release
sudo yum install yum-plugin-copr
sudo yum copr enable ngompa/snapcore-el7
sudo yum -y install snapd
sudo systemctl enable --now snapd.socket
```

Then install heroku toolbelt:

```
sudo snap install --classic heroku
```

**Deploying to docker image to heroku:**

In Jenkins scripted pipeline:

```
withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'heroku-api-cred', variable: 'herokuRegistryApiCred')]) {
        sh "docker login -u email@example.com -p ${herokuRegistryApiCred} registry.heroku.com"          
    }
    // Tag docker img (in my case it was an image in dockerhub)
    sh "docker tag dockerhubusername/pvtreponame:${imageTag} registry.heroku.com/your_app_name/release_type[ie>web]"
    sh "docker push registry.heroku.com/your_app_name/web"
    sh "/usr/local/bin/heroku container:release web --app=your_app_name"
    sh "docker logout registry.heroku.com"
```

In order to run the app inside docker (in my case it was java) I had to add the below line (otherwise it was crashing because 1. tell app about heroku's port binding. 2. tell web process to run command. The ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","my_spring_boot_app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"] does not work on heroku.):

```
CMD ["web", "java $JAVA_OPTS -Dserver.port=$PORT -jar /usr/app/my_spring_boot_app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```